# UPDATE SQL Query with joins

Tags: ms-access, ibm-midrange

I'm getting the following error:

> Syntax error(missing operator ) in query expression UTRTEN=6

Code:

```
UPDATE HTEDTAT.UT101AP 

set UTRTEN=3

where UTRTEN=6 

FROM HTEDTAT_UT101AP a 

INNER JOIN HTEDTAT_UT200AP 

INNER JOIN HTEDTAT_UT220AP 

ON HTEDTAT_UT200AP.UTCSID = HTEDTAT_UT220AP.UTCSID

ON HTEDTAT_UT101AP.UTLCID = HTEDTAT_UT220AP.UTLCID

WHERE HTEDTAT_UT200AP.UTCSZP=22204;
```

Comment: Syntax error(missing operator ) in query expression UTRTEN=6

Comment: UPDATE HTEDTAT.UT101AP 
SET  HTEDTAT.UT101AP.UTRTEN='3'
From HTEDTAT.UT101AP a
Inner join INNER JOIN HTEDTAT_UT220AP 
ON HTEDTAT_UT101AP.UTLCID = HTEDTAT_UT220AP.UTLCID
INNER JOIN HTEDTAT_UT200AP
ON HTEDTAT_UT200AP.UTCSID = HTEDTAT_UT220AP.UTCSID
WHERE HTEDTAT_UT200AP.UTCSZP='22204'
AND a.UTRTEN=6;